# Away from the hub

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, computer-puzzle

Today I got a weird FaceTime call from teenage girl I didn't know. They must have dialled the wrong number, but I was too intrigued to hang up. Instead, I covered my camera and turned off the microphone on my end.

> *I had to go out from my house to go shopping, but it was the worst experience! I think I had a hallucination! I couldn't wait to be back home, so I could look up what was wrong and tell all my friends about it. I don't know... can you help me understand why it happened? It seemed pretty extreme, but a lot of my friends say they've experienced the same longing feeling, and don't know why either.*
>
> I saw a whole lot of images in my hallucination, and I swear I could hear things... in different languages...
>
> - The first thing I saw was a fish, but instead of being smooth, it had right-angled corners all the way around.
> - Next I saw a couple of blue and yellow snakes. Then there were three snakes. After that, just one, but a third of its body had been removed!
> - I saw a yellow and black animal, with a variety of mushrooms in it. However, it looked like parts of the mushrooms had been cut off.
> - After that, two images side by side. One was a brain, and the other was the right half of a watch. It looked like a kids watch, and it was apparently made by Swatch
> - The next thing I saw was, oh, I've forgotten the name for it. If you click the globe button on the keyboard, you'll probably see its name.
> - I saw an image of some train tracks.
> - Next it looked like the night sky on a clear night out in the country.
> - Finally, I saw an image of what was going on in the centre of the sun.
>
> When I recovered, I was filled with a deep sense of longing. I also had some writing on my hand - I must have scribbled it on myself when I passed out with my pen. It looked like this:
>
> ```
> #79v0";nn78             +00             +00             +00
> #   -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
> #  179➡
> #  9
> #  +*
> # +8
> #  *             + *
> #  .     +     +     +     +     +     +     +     +     +     +     +     +
> #  @
> print(int(79-4*(1/2)))
> '''({}{}()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())
> $ 'main' (--)
>  \
>   \-[66]o-#R'6!'5O'''
> ```

---

*(Hereon is not part of the puzzle, just some random notes)*

<sup>This story is based on a fictional event and taken from there...</sup>

Part of an upcoming <kbd>[metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd>.

Comment: That's... clever! Must have been hard to find code that worked as such!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It wasn't actually \*that\* hard - most of the code is separate. I might post a small wrap-up and some time, perhaps...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code block is

> A polyglot, i.e. programming code that can be run in multiple languages at once. Knowing @boboquack, many of these languages, esoteric or otherwise, are commonly seen on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

The first thing I saw was a fish, but instead of being smooth, it had right-angled corners all the way around.

> Running the code in [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) gives [78](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

Next I saw a couple of blue and yellow snakes.

> Running the code in Python 2 gives [79](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ). This line reference's [Python](https://www.python.org/)'s blue and yellow logo.

Then there were three snakes.

> Running the code in Python 3 gives [77](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

After that, just one, but a third of its body had been removed!

> Running the code in [Pyth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth) gives [79](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ) (Thanks @Ankoganit!)

I saw a yellow and black animal, with a variety of mushrooms in it. However, it looked like parts of the mushrooms had been cut off.

> Running the code in [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93) gives [80](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

After that, two images side by side. One was a brain, and the other was the right half of a watch. It looked like a kids watch, and it was apparently made by Swatch

> Running the code in [Brain-Flak](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brain-Flak) gives [72](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

The next thing I saw was, oh, I've forgotten the name for it. If you click the globe button on the keyboard, you'll probably see its name.

> Running the code in [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji) gives [79](https://tio.run/nexus/emoji#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

I saw an image of some train tracks.

> Running the code in [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail) gives [66](https://tio.run/nexus/rail#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

Next it looked like the night sky on a clear night out in the country.

> Running the code in [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry) gives [73](https://tio.run/nexus/starry#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

Finally, I saw an image of what was going on in the centre of the sun.

> Running the code in [Fission](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission) gives [65](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#@69sbllmoGSdl2duoYAMtA0MCPG5lIG0rpauQnJ@SmZeupVCZnG@roWFqaWuoSlIHCRv@GH@pDXmliDy0byFIBFLEKGtBSS1LUBMLVRjFUAyCnpQDsUkyDAHroKizLwSDRA2t9Q10dIw1DfS1NTkUldX16iura7V0Bw8UJNLRUE9NzEzT11BQ1dXk0shhktBIUY32swsNl9XOUjdTFHd1B/o8P//AQ)

Putting it all together:

> `78 79 77 79 80 72 79 66 73 65` is ASCII for `NOMOPHOBIA`, a proposed name for [the fear of being without your cell phone](https://web.archive.org/web/20080412042610/http://www.wsbt.com/news/health/17263604.html)

Comment: I believe I'm missing an O from the answer.

Comment: I believe the second line mentions Python 2 (couple of snakes), Python 3( three snakes ) and Pyth (a third of its body ~on~ removed).

Comment: Ah, of course. That would explain the stray quote on the first line.

Comment: Just wondering, did you use the 'cache hit (**learn more**)' function of TIO to your advantage? I'll accept as well, but in around 6-10 hours.

Comment: @boboquack Not really - I recognised [most of the languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78292/21487) from the code alone :P

Comment: Would it be unkindly pedantic to remark that fission is not in fact what's going on in the centre of the sun? (Of course a random teenager might well get it wrong...)

Answer (score 5):

Most of the metaphors are still beyond my comprehension, but for starters, I'll try to spoil some of them.

Blue and yellow snakes:

> The Python programming language. Running the code in Python outputs 79.

Yellow and black animal with mushrooms:

> This is almost certainly Befunge (bee-fung[us]), an esoteric language. The code does terminate in a Befunge interpreter (it reaches the @ character), but it outputs nothing. Maybe it needs some input?

Brain:

> Probably a reference to Brainf__k. The Brainf__k characters in the code:
>  
>  +++------+++.++++++++++++----[]-
>  
>  The code doesn't terminate. It writes 8 to the zero offset, then enters an infinite loop.

Train tracks:

> Might be Ruby on Rails. I haven't tried this one out yet.

Comment: "Finally, I saw an image of what was going on in the centre of the sun." - might be about "wnin" (rot13 to not spoil it).

Comment: @Marius Oh, 'Sun'. That's nice.

Comment: @Marius Sadly, it doesn't compile in that language. There's also a markup language called PbyqShfvba, but that's not what is happening inside the Sun.